# WPF orientation on Windows Surface

Tags: c#, wpf

We have a C# WPF application that works great across every Windows tablet we have tested with except for the Microsoft Surface. Our app is specifically set to only run in portrait mode, for example, and yet when you run the app on a Surface the orientation rotates based on the orientation of the device.

No other device behaves this way. Its as if the Surface overrides any orientation settings that are set in the app and decides for itself what orientation to use.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Hello I see this is old, but how did you "specifically set to only run in portrait mode".